# Importing just library.a file and using it without adding its header files in iOS

Tags: ios, static-libraries, header-files

I have created library. Now I want to just add .a file of the library in my new project and use the methods inside library. I am getting an error. It doesn't allow me to import any .h file of library, It just can't find any header files inside library. Please someone guide how to use the library with just .a file

Answer (score 0):

The .h files are not contained within the library. You need to add them to the project explicitly so you can reference them.